# Find the parameter $\alpha$ that ....

Tags: polynomials

My question is: For which value of the real parameter $\alpha$ the following equation has a root with the multiplicity higher than $1$.

$$3x^4+4x^3-6x^2-12x+\alpha=0$$

$Thank $  $you$ $!!!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $a$ is a root of $\displaystyle f(x)=3x^4+4x^3−6x^2−12x+\alpha=0$ with the multiplicity $>1$

$\displaystyle f(a)=f'(a)=0$